# Filter database names in sql server using GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several databases in my sql server in which some of them I have created from my application and the database name would be a GUID . On the other hand I have some engagements without name in GUID format.

however , I would like to know how do I filter the engagements which I have created from my application  (which have GUID format).

Can anyone create a query to get the databases with name in GUID format . any help would be appreciated .

```
select * from sys.databases where ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starts with a `{` and ends with a `}` and length is `38`.

```
select *
from sys.databases
where name like '{%}' and 
      len(name) = 38
```

Or

```
select *
from sys.databases
where name like '{________-____-____-____-____________}'
```

If you really want it *safe* you can use this

```
select *
from sys.databases
where name like '{________-____-____-____-____________}' and
      patindex('{%[^-0-9A-F]%}', name) = 0
```

Comment: Like ZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZ ? 8-) Just kidding.

Comment: @OlegDok - :) Well... you could replace all `_` with `[0-9A-F]` but that is probably overdoing it.

Comment: +1 I am too lazy to write such a long LIKE. Cursor is easier 8-) Even if cursors are evil.

Comment: @OlegDok - Think I found a way without the **very** long like expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from sys.databases where LEN(name) = 36
```

or

```
DECLARE @dbs TABLE (NAME sysname)

DECLARE c CURSOR for
SELECT name FROM sys.databases

DECLARE @name sysname

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
      IF CAST(@name AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) <> NEWID() PRINT 'Match'

      INSERT @dbs values(@name)

    END TRY
    begin CATCH
    END CATCH
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name

END
CLOSE c DEALLOCATE c

SELECT * FROM @dbs
```

Comment: Thanks , i don't have the value in advance . I need all the engagements with Name in GUID FORMAT (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).